# How to match foreign keys in MongoDB and perform following complex queries?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My database has 3 Collections :

1. Tour, 2) turism_ind, 3) customer

```
> db.tour.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622385ab1b68d9136e48ba51"),
    "source" : "Pune",
    "destination" : "Kashmir"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52"),
    "source" : "Mumbai",
    "destination" : "Shilong"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622385ce1b68d9136e48ba53"),
    "source" : "Nashik",
    "destination" : "Goa"
}
```

---

```
> db.turism_ind.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6223885d1b68d9136e48ba57"),
    "ind_name" : "Veena World",
    "package" : [
        {
            "pkg_id" : 111,
            "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52"),
            "cost" : 85000
        }
    ],
    "cust_review" : [
        {
            "cust_id" : ObjectId("622387fa1b68d9136e48ba56"),
            "rating" : 4
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622389191b68d9136e48ba58"),
    "ind_name" : "GK Travels",
    "package" : [
        {
            "pkg_id" : 222,
            "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52"),
            "cost" : 82000
        },
        {
            "pkg_id" : 223,
            "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ab1b68d9136e48ba51"),
            "cost" : 78000
        }
    ],
    "cust_review" : [
        {
            "cust_id" : ObjectId("622387f51b68d9136e48ba55"),
            "rating" : 5
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622389ae1b68d9136e48ba59"),
    "ind_name" : "KK Tours",
    "package" : [
        {
            "pkg_id" : 333,
            "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ce1b68d9136e48ba53"),
            "cost" : 57000
        },
        {
            "pkg_id" : 334,
            "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ab1b68d9136e48ba51"),
            "cost" : 79000
        }
    ],
    "cust_review" : [
        {
            "cust_id" : ObjectId("622387f51b68d9136e48ba55"),
            "rating" : 5
        },
        {
            "cust_id" : ObjectId("622387ef1b68d9136e48ba54"),
            "rating" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

---

```
 > db.customer.find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622387ef1b68d9136e48ba54"),
    "cust_name" : "Aniket",
    "selected_pkg" : [
        111
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622387f51b68d9136e48ba55"),
    "cust_name" : "Nik",
    "selected_pkg" : [
        222,
        333,
        334
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("622387fa1b68d9136e48ba56"),
    "cust_name" : "Sham",
    "selected_pkg" : [
        111,
        222
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62238c671b68d9136e48ba5a"),
    "cust_name" : "John",
    "selected_pkg" : [
        111,
        222,
        223,
        333,
        334
    ]
}
```

I want to perform the following queries :

> 1] List all the details of expenses made by John on his first 3 trips.
> Also display the total expenses
>
> 2] List the names of the customers who went on a tour to Shillong. [5]

It is possible to perform those queries on the given document or document structure is wrong?

I try this for 1st query

```
db.turism_ind.aggregate(
   {$unwind : "$package"}, 
   {$match : { "package.pkg_id" : {$in : [111,222,333] } } }, 
   {$project :{ _id : 0 , package : 1, total_cost : {$sum : "$package.cost"} }}
)
```

Output (Not Correct)

```
{ "package" : { "pkg_id" : 111, "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52"),  "cost" : 85000 }, "total_cost" :  85000 }

{ "package" : { "pkg_id" : 222, "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52"), "cost" : 82000 }, "total_cost" : 82000 }

{ "package" : { "pkg_id" : 333, "tour_id" : ObjectId("622385ce1b68d9136e48ba53"), "cost" : 57000 }, "total_cost" : 57000 }
```

Comment: Please give more sample documents, and how do you know which package is John's first 3 trips?

Comment: Ok.! I added more sample documents. John's first three packages are 111,222,223 which is selected_pkg[0],selected_pkg[1],selected_pkg[2].I store package id in array in collection of customer.

Comment: Hii Koodies please help me..! This database will be in my practical exam..!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the aggregation for your first part. There might be some bug depending on your other documents inside your collections.

Here's a quick breakdown of your question.

`List all the details of expenses made by John`
Utilize $match to get john document

`on his first 3 trips.`
Utilize $project to slice the first 3 elements out and the do a $lookup on the turism_ind to grab the necessary documents

`Also display the total expenses`
Had to utilize the $reduce in a projection to flatten 2D array into 1D, and follow by another project to $sum all the cost together as total.

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AfLJ6RfClAx)

```
db.customer.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cust_name": "John"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "firstThree": {
        "$slice": [
          "$selected_pkg",
          0,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "turism_ind",
      "localField": "firstThree",
      "foreignField": "package.pkg_id",
      "as": "tour"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "packages": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$tour.package",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "packages": 1,
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$packages.cost"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result

```
[
  {
    "packages": [
      {
        "cost": 85000,
        "pkg_id": 111,
        "tour_id": ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52")
      },
      {
        "cost": 82000,
        "pkg_id": 222,
        "tour_id": ObjectId("622385ba1b68d9136e48ba52")
      },
      {
        "cost": 78000,
        "pkg_id": 223,
        "tour_id": ObjectId("622385ab1b68d9136e48ba51")
      }
    ],
    "total": 245000
  }
]
```